# Jquery UI Timepicker not working with same ID/Name inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, timepicker

http://jsfiddle.net/cblaze22/Duzr4/1/

Is there a way around getting http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/ to work nice with inputs that have the same ID/Name?

Comment: It is invalid to have to objects with the same id. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't force jQuery to play nice with invalid HTML a document with duplicated `id` attributes is invalid; from the [fine specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute):

> *3.2.3.1 The id attribute*
>   [...]
>   The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree

and in your case, the *home subtree* is probably your whole page.

Fix your HTML to not duplicate `id` attributes and switch to a different selector:

```
$('input[name=test]').timepicker();
```

or add a class to your `<input>`s and select on that class:

```
<input name="test" type="text" class="timepicker" />
<input name="test" type="text" class="timepicker" />
```

and:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/VhBXK/

​